# How to sum up pandas columns only if the last digit of a column is less equal the last digit of this one

Tags: pandas, dataframe

So I have a pandas dataframe like this

| contract | account | number1 | number2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A | 3 | 1 |
| B1 | B | 2 | 2 |
| A2 | A | 1 | 3 |
| A3 | A | 5 | 5 |
| B2 | B | 3 | 4 |
| C1 | C | 3 | 3 |

and I want to add two columns that sum up the number columns so far so for example, for A1 it would just be the numbers for A1, for A2 it would be the numbers for A1 and A2, for A3 it would be  sum1 = number1 for A1 + number1 for A2 + number1 for A3, and so on.  Basically sum the columns everything else with the same account whose last number of contract is less than the current one.

| contract | account | number1 | number2 | sum1 | sum2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A | 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| B1 | B | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| A2 | A | 1 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
| A3 | A | 5 | 5 | 9 | 8 |
| B2 | B | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| C1 | C | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assign, groupby and cumsum

```
df=df.assign(sum1=df.groupby('account')['number1'].cumsum(),sum2=df.groupby('account')['number2'].cumsum())



  contract account  number1  number2  sum1  sum2
0       A1       A        3        1     3     1
1       B1       B        2        2     2     2
2       A2       A        1        3     4     4
3       A3       A        5        5     9     9
4       B2       B        3        4     5     6
5       C1       C        3        3     3     3
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, sort the values and `groupby+agg`:

```
df.join(
 df.sort_values(by='contract')
   .groupby('account')
   .agg(sum1=('number1','cumsum'),
        sum2=('number2','cumsum'))
 )
```

Output:

```
  contract account  number1  number2  sum1  sum2
0       A1       A        3        1     3     1
1       B1       B        2        2     2     2
2       A2       A        1        3     4     4
3       A3       A        5        5     9     9
4       B2       B        3        4     5     6
5       C1       C        3        3     3     3
```

Comment: "sorry the values"? :D

Comment: @richardec typing on a phone, autocorrect is a pain ;)

Comment: Lol, yeah. But I'm surprised you can even get as far as you did on a phone...like even the formatted dataframe?

Comment: Running python ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` + `cumsum`:

```
df[['sum1', 'sum2']] = df.groupby('account')[['number1', 'number2']].cumsum()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  contract account  number1  number2  sum1  sum2
0       A1       A        3        1     3     1
1       B1       B        2        2     2     2
2       A2       A        1        3     4     4
3       A3       A        5        5     9     9
4       B2       B        3        4     5     6
5       C1       C        3        3     3     3
```